Linear Temporal Logic - Statements about formulas
I am trying to understand the implications of 2 LTL formulas.
Formula 1: P W false
(Let P be a propositional symbol)
I have the following statements, some of which are unrelated, meaning that they're wrong in the context of this formula (they cannot be inferred from it).
1- P must always be false.
2- It must be the case that ¬P holds in at least one state.
3- P must always hold.
4- ¬P should not hold in any state.
So far I could not connect any of these statements to the given formula.
The formula merely requires that P holds in all states until maybe in a future state false holds, which doesn't seem to be connected to any of the given statements.
Formula 2: (X F M) U P
(Let P be a propositional symbol)
There are again some statements, some of which are incorrect.
1- P must hold in the second state or M must hold sometime after the first state in which P holds
2- P must hold in the first state or M must start to hold sometime after the first state in which P holds
3- M must start to hold sometime after the first state in which P holds
4- M must hold sometime after the first state in which P holds
I again couldn't connect any of these statements to the given formula.
The formula requires that the next state must eventually be M until the state in which P holds, which will definitely come in the future.
I would really appreciate your help.

See LTL: "ψ W φ" reads "Weak until: ψ has to hold at least until φ; if φ never becomes true, ψ must remain true forever." Thus, $P \text { W False}$ means that $P$ has to hold until False; but False never becomes true.

Thank you. In a similar fashion, could it be said that the formula false W P is unsatisfiable?

@ppch I think if P is true at w, then false W P is true at w as well
